# Property 'open' does not exist on type 'MatDialogModule'

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

Just beginning building Angular apps. I'm writing a small book-inventory app. I'm having trouble with the **Dialog component** from the **Material Module**. I've visited the Angular material website to check my implementation and still have not been able to get it to behave as intended. I'm having a *similar problem* with the **snackbar component**. Wondering if anyone has run across this problem before. Thanks for your help!

**app.Module.ts**

```
import {MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';

imports:[MatDialogModule]
```

**collection.component.ts**

```
import {MatDialogModule, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';

bookDetailDialogRef: MatDialogRef<BookDetailComponent>;

constructor(private dataService: DataService, private snackBar: MatSnackBarModule,
              private _dialog: MatDialogModule, private _router: Router){}

openDialog(bookId: number): void{
    let config = {with: '650px', height: '400px', position: {top: '50px'}};
    let dialogRef = this._dialog.open(this.bookDetailDialogRef, config);
    dialogRef.componentInstance.bookId = bookId;
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(res => {this.getBooks();});
  }
```

**collection.component.html**

```
<button mat-button (click)="openDialog(book.id)"><i class="material-icons">
              pageview</i> Dialog</button>
```

Answer (score 10):

_dialog is of type **`MatDialog`** not **MatDialogModule** and  change **MatSnackBarModule** to **`MatSnackBar`**. In your constructor change it as,

```
constructor(private dataService: DataService, private snackBar: MatSnackBarModule,
              private _dialog: MatDialog, private _router: Router){}
```

Comment: Also change `MatSnackBarModule` to `MatSnackBar`.

Comment: @Sajeetharan It worked perfectly! Thank you! That was a big help!

Answer (score -1):

Replace  `MatDialogModule` with `MatDialog`

```
constructor(

public dialog: MatDialog

)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.